# how to switch to the IS operator when operand value is NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a mysql column that is `INT`, It can contain `0` and It's also `NULL`able

Currently I'm using this:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    `mytable`
WHERE
    IF(:mydata IS NULL, `mycolumn` IS NULL, `mycolumn` = :mydata)
```

But I wonder if there is there a shorter and conciser way to get the same result

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can also use `IN` on your column. `where mycolumn in ( null, :mydata )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) comparison operator for NULL-safe comparison:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    `mytable`
WHERE
    `mycolumn` <=> :mydata
```

Answer (score 1):

May not be shorter but more readable way is to use `OR`, like this:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    `mytable`
WHERE
    mycolumn IS NULL OR mycolumn = :mydata
```

It will return rows having `NULL` value in `mycolumn` in addition to rows which exactly match with `mydata`.